# Getting region error while using aws ses service in mongodb stitch app

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, mongodb-stitch

I am using AWS SES service for sending email in stitch App of mongodb. my stitch app is registered on region Oregon (us-west-2). but when I send email every time I get this type of error.[image]
I want to know that my application is registered on Oregon (us-west-2) but why i am getting error related to US-EAST-1.

> StitchError: MessageRejected: Email address is not verified. The
>   following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1:
>   muhazzib7@gmail.com status code: 400, request id:
>   1e7cc347-fc56-11e8-8fd9-47e8eaf4f2d3

Answer (score 0):

The aws service will default to US-EAST-1, not the region that your app is in. You must input the region when you call the service like: `context.services.get("aws").ses("us-west-2").SendEmail({...})`.

You also have to make sure that you verify the email address with Amazon for each region that you want to use it with. Here's some [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/ses-errors.html) on sending failures.

Comment: You could not input the region in stitch functions while using aws service. It should use the region in which the application is registered as per their docs.

Comment: Can you link the docs that say that? The region that the Stitch app is registered in and the region that the aws services use are completely different.

Comment: The region that you use for the aws service in this case should be the region that the email address is registered for with Amazon, and that could be different from the region that you chose to use for the whole Stitch app.

Comment: Please link the official doc of mongodb stitch app where this method is used or described which you have given.
context.services.get("aws").ses("us-west-2").Send({...})

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/reference/partner-services/amazon-service/ (should be SendEmail())